# Proper datatype for storing 'μm' in database?

Tags: abap, sap-pi

**Problem**

I need to put some values into Z-table with unit, which are not in SAP standard(micron).

EDIT : I'm talking about 'μm' itself, not it's meaning - I made table which have 'unit' field, which are putting 'μm' inside that field, and 'value' field, which are int which have it's thickness - like, 30.

So I can use it to Report - like showing, 'this specific material have 30μm thickness'.

**Question**

I got that data from PI - which are sending that values from legacy system (might be unicode-based).
I have to put that data, using ABAP, to my Z-table.

1. Do I safe to set field type, Char length 2(like um, not *μm*)?
2. How can I do comparision logic for special values [ex) If f1 = 'μm'.]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: 'μ' is present in the UC2-charset (00B5 MICRO SIGN), so is exactly 1 abap char. So comparsion and storing it in a table should work fine. Did you encounter any issues?

Comment: @peterulb Test shows there is no problem with comparison, except it seems ugly in SE80 - Just watch out to being ' Μ ', which converts into 'M' in SAP. Use 'μ' to get clean result - It seems if you manually put data in Z-table, 'μm' automatically turns 'Μm', which turns 'MM'.

Comment: Anyway.. Can you answer the question so i can pick you as a answer one? I think someone need this answer, who are using exotic letter when they using SAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of the right length is answered in the documentation of [Built-In Character-Like Types](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abenbuiltin_types_character.htm).

> - When specifying lengths for character-like types, note that the length of a character in bytes depends on the character representation used. For the character representation UCS-2 used by the ABAP programming language, the length of a character is two bytes.

Regarding UCS-2:

> **UCS-2**
>
> Two byte Unicode character representation. In this representation, all characters are represented by two bytes (16 bits). In UCS-2, 65536 different characters can be encoded, that correspond to the so called Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) of the Unicode standard. In contrast to UTF-16, UCS-2 does not support characters from the surrogate area. The ABAP programming language supports UCS-2 in Unicode systems and therefore no surrogates.

```
DATA(lv_x) = ''. "C length 2
DATA(lv_y) = 'μ'. "C length 1
```

Since `μ` is present in the UC2-charset (00B5 MICRO SIGN), it will occupy one character in ABAP and can be stored and compared as such.
You might be able to change the character representation of a database table, but as soon as ABAP reads from it, it will be converted to UCS-2.

Reading a UTF-8 File with the content `μm` works just fine

```
cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog( CHANGING file_table  = lt_files
                                                     rc          = lv_rc
                                                     user_action = lv_action ).
IF lv_action <> cl_gui_frontend_services=>action_ok OR lv_rc <> 1.
  RETURN.
ENDIF.

DATA lt_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string.
cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload( EXPORTING filename = |{ lt_files[ 1 ]-filename }|
                                                filetype = 'ASC'
                                                codepage = '4110'
                                      CHANGING  data_tab = lt_tab ).
DATA(lv_text) = REDUCE string( INIT s = `` FOR <lv_line> IN lt_tab NEXT s = s && <lv_line> ).
DATA(lv_unit) = CONV zmy_units-unit( lv_text ).
INSERT zmy_units FROM @( VALUE zmy_units(
    unit        = lv_text
    description = 'Test' ) ).

SELECT SINGLE * FROM zmy_units WHERE unit = 'μm' INTO @DATA(ls_unit).
WRITE ls_unit-unit.
NEW-LINE.
WRITE |{ xsdbool( ls_unit-unit = 'μm' ) }|.

* Result
* μm
* X
```

More information regarding encoding via RFC can be found in [Conversions in Accordance with the SAP Standard - Communication Using Remote Function Calls](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ERP_SPV/c4e98fcb44e74814b58b61aefc1b1fcb/1da1ce5314894208e10000000a174cb4.html?version=6.06.21).